# .htaccess url rewrite from forward slash to none like facebook

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If you understand what I mean, please kindly give me answers of my issue as the follwoing:

By using .HTACCESS, I want to rewrite the user profile URL which is ended by "/" to none.

Ex: http://v.com/username/ --> http://v.com/username like facebook does.

The browser show 404 error if the URL contained forward slash at the end. It tells the browser point to a directory but, not a file.

This is what I have done:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this rule at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] # Remove trailing slash
```